# Select list-element with special character

Tags: r, list, special-characters

I am trying to subset a list, based on special characters attached to the elements. I found multiple results, but I think I lack the understand on how to deal with special characters and find elements containing special characters. I would like to have a result with all the elements containing '**' at the end. I appreciate any help and I apologize if there was a similar question already, which I did not found. A general answer on dealing with special characters when subsetting a list will also be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Example-Code:

```
x1 <- c('a**', 'b', 'c**')
x2 <- c('d**', 'b', 'e**')

y <- list(x1,x2)

#Here are a couple of results i tried:

grep('\\**', y, value =TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)

y[lapply(y, function(x) x[grep("[^\\**]", x),])]

Filter(function(x) !any(grepl("[^\\**]", x)), y)

y[y = "[^\\**]"]
```

Comment: `grep("\\*\\*", unlist(y), value = TRUE)`. You need to escape (\\\) it for each *

Comment: Thank you! That was very fast!

Comment: Or `grep("\\*{2}$", unlist(y), value = TRUE)` which is easier if you have larger number of repetitions and the dollar sign ensures it's at the end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` with `fixed=TRUE`

```
grep("**", unlist(y), value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "a**" "c**" "d**" "e**"
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to answer my question, but I am unable to understand the solution you provided within the context of my question. Could you please further elaborate?

Comment: @Simon Please check the `grep` output.  I guess that is what you wanted>

Comment: Thank you. The grep output works perfectly, however, the substring unfortunately not for selecting the elements.